# Render multiple MongoDB collections in same path (Express)

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, vue.js

I have get method in my Express app, which renders a collection from my MongoDB called "Members". This works find, and I'm able to read the result on the url "/agileApp". However, I want to render another collection into the same URL - a collections called "Tasks". Is this possible? Here are my current code:

```
expressApp.get('/agileApp', function(request, response) {
    MongoClient.connect(url,
        {useUnifiedTopology: true},
        function(error, db) {
            if (error) {
                throw error;
            }
            let databaseobject = db.db(dbName);
                databaseobject.collection("Members").find().toArray(function (err, result) {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    response.render('agileApp', {
                        result: result,
                    });
                    db.close();
                });
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just take a request parameter for deciding which collection to render and depending on that value render that collection.

```
expressApp.get('/agileApp', function(request, response) {
// take the collection to render as request parameter (this is form parameter, json also can be used)
let collectionToRender = request.params.collectionToRender
MongoClient.connect(url,
    {useUnifiedTopology: true},
    function(error, db) {
        if (error) {
            throw error;
        }
        let databaseobject = db.db(dbName);
            // here it will query the mongodb for the collection which has been provided in the request
            // if user enters Tasks then Tasks collection will be rendered
            databaseobject.collection(collectionToRender).find().toArray(function (err, result) {
                if (err) throw err;
                response.render('agileApp', {
                    result: result,
                });
                db.close();
            });
    });
  });
```

Comment: So the users dont really enter anything. I just need two collections to be rendered when /agileApp is entered.